# Efficient way to replace incorrect words in Series of strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm working with text data, that is handwritten, so it has lots of ortographic errors. I'm currently working with `pyspellchecker` to clean the data and I'm using the `correct()` method to find the most likely word when a word doesn't exist. My approach was to create a dictionary with all poorly written words as keys and the most likely word as value:

```
dic={}
for i in df.text:
    misspelled = spell.unknown(i.split())
    for word in misspelled:
        dic[word]=spell.correction(word)
```

Even though this is working, it is doing so very slowly. Thus, I wanted to know if there's a faster option to implement this. Do you have any ideas?

Edit: there are 10571 rows in df.text and strings are usually 5-15 words long. Each loop is taking around 3-5 seconds, which makes for a total of around 40000 seconds to run the whole loop.

Comment: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: How long are the strings contained in each element of df.text? How many elements are there in df.text?

Comment: @sphennings i edited what you asked, thanks !

Comment: @Chris, I'll see if I can vectorize this operation somehow, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is create a mapping from the misspelled words you encountered to their the suggestion, you can reduce the size of the dataset by removing duplicate words. This will minimize the number of calls to `spell.unknown` and `spell.correction`, as well prevent unneeded updates to the contents of the dictionary.

```py
uniquewords = set().union(*(sentence.split() for sentence in df.text))
corrections = {word: spell.correction(word) for word in spell.unknown(uniquewords)}
```

Comment: `uniquewords = set().union(*(sentence.split() for sentence in df.text))` probably will be more efficient by skipping extra string operation

Comment: @Marat You're probably right. I was unaware of set().union. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could try pd.apply instead of doing a loop:

```
eng = pd.Series(['EmpName', 'EMP_NAME', 'EMP.NAME', 'EMPName', 'CUSTOMIR', 'TIER187CAST', 'MultipleTIMESTAMPinTABLE', 'USD$'])
eng = eng.str.lower()
eng = eng.str.split()
spell = SpellChecker()
def msp(x):
    return spell.unknown(x)
eng.apply(msp)
```